# Any listener methods to know the end time of job in quartz schedular?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

In my application Ive to schedule the jobs with the start time and end time.

```
    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().startAt(startDate).endAt(endDate)
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()).build();
```

During the start time I  have to call some methods and while it
 reaches the end time it should call some other methods. And also my job is single time execution. Is there any listener methods fire at end time.? I tried using  *triggerFininshed() method*  but its firing when there is no more trigger left over. I want Listener to fire at end time only.

Comment: As such even i'm not able to find.

Comment: But some other way im doing now. Instead of having trigger with start time and end time you can have separate triggers . so When end trigger fired you can call **listener** methods very well.